# How to Add Data to Custom Content for Dynamic Table - Datatable JQuery

Tags: datatables

I am working with Datatable and trying to add data that coming from ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "data/arrays.txt",
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": -1,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": "<button>Click!</button>"
    } ]
  } );

} );
```

the code above is working however but I want embed data with **defaultContent**

Example:

For: {"data": "id"}

```
"defaultContent":"<a href='address/id'</a>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`columns.render`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) instead as shown below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.txt",
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null,
            "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
               if(type === 'display'){
                  data = '<a href="address/' + full[0] + '">Click</a>';
               }

               return data;
            }
       } ]
    } );
} );
```

If you're using array of objects as you data source use `full['id']` instead of `full[0]` but you need to add column definitions with `columns.data` option as shown in [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html).

Comment: Thanks for the solution.However I faced another problem now  How to add inside  Laravel (Blade engine?) <a href='{{ route('logs.edit',['id'=>id]) }} . Concatenation doesn't work, maybe I should create another question...